# Trying to read in data from a CSV file, list index out of range?

Tags: python, csv

I have no idea why this isn't working, I've done this before with CSV files and it worked. The file has no blank lines or blank values and the data is separated by commas. This is what I have:

```
#Create empty lists for data.
Date = []
Open = []
High = []
Low = []
Close = []
Adj_Close = []
Volume = []

#Fill lists with data.
with open("AAPL_train.csv", "r") as infile:
    for lines in infile:
        lines = lines.split(",")
        Date.append(lines[0])
        Open.append(lines[1])
        High.append(lines[2])
        Low.append(lines[3])
        Close.append(lines[4])
        Adj_Close.append(lines[5])
        Volume.append(lines[6])
```

My error code is reading that it goes out of index at the  `Open.append(lines[1])` line.

Then here is a [sample of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obzzk.png) to show you what it looks like.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Edited to add: The error I'm getting is IndexError: list index out of range on line 18, and when I try to do a print line after each loop, I get nothing but the error.

Comment: Next time don't forget to give us all the traceBack Error.

Comment: add a print(line) just after new for loop

Comment: Have you done any basic debugging? e.g., try to catch the index error, and print the offending line?

Comment: Also, you might check out the native csv module instead of parsing it by yourself: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: If the line doesn’t include a `,` then `lines[1]` will give an index error. You could very easily print `lines` before where the error occurs. Or code defensively - not really an option IMO, you should always code defensively - and check `len(lines)>1`. Yes you should really use the `csv` module because it will handle the details that your simplistic diy approach won’t, for example , with a quoted value, but you should still check the number of values read from the line before assuming the nth value exists. Bet you don’t get the error on your sample, do you?

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

#Create empty lists for data.
Date = []
Open = []
High = []
Low = []
Close = []
Adj_Close = []
Volume = []

#Fill lists with data.
with open("AAPL_train.csv", "r") as infile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=','):
        # skip header
        next(csv_reader)
        for row in infile:
            Date.append(row[0])
            Open.append(row[1])
            High.append(row[2])
            Low.append(row[3])
            Close.append(row[4])
            Adj_Close.append(row[5])
            Volume.append(row[6])
```

I've updated your code to use the inbuilt python csv package. It makes life easier when dealing with CSV and its generator should help prevent any memory problems down the line!

I also added the `next(csv_reader)` call in order to skip the header in your csv data. I made the assumption this was data you may not actually want to record.

Answer (score 0):

Try using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(AAPL_train.csv)

Date = df['Date'].tolist()
Open = df['Open'].tolist()
High = df['High'].tolist()
Low = df['Low'].tolist()
Close = df['Close'].tolist()
Adj_Close = df['Adj_Close'].tolist()
Volume = df['Volume'].tolist()
```